# Indexing Tweets in Lucene

Tags: lucene

At the moment I have a number of tweets that I want to index, however each of them is in small document. If I were to aggregate them into say 100 tweets per file, is it possible to use Lucene to index them but at the same time maintain the tweet ID (ID column present in the file)?

For instance, each row it looks like below:

```
TweetID | TweetText
```

Thanks,
Andy.

Comment: Please reformat it as a question. What exactly makes difficulty for you, and how can the others help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr calls these "multivalued fields" and the way they accomplish it is via offsets. Basically, you allocate say 200 bytes per tweet, then set the offset of the nth tweet to start at 200*offset.

When searching, you can get back the offset of the matched tweet, and from there figure out which tweet matched.

Comment: let's say I reserve 20 digit for the TweetID and 140 characters for the Tweet text = 160 byte + another 40 byte for other info, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, you can reserve whatever amount you think is necessary. Lucene uses a sparse storage format, so you can set the offsets to be essentially whatever you like without paying a storage penalty.